# How do I copy and paste ob VBA disposed as a matriz?

Tags: vba, excel, paste

guys!

I have a template of a card, and then I want to create print pages, with 175 of them, each page should have 3x3 cards. So far so good, but i'm having error 1004, when pasting the copied cells into the new "row", if I may say. Follow the code:

```
Dim originalWs As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim wsRowCounter As Long, wsCollumCounter As Long, expansionSize As Long, cardRowSize As Long, cardCollumSize As Long
Dim horizontalCardsPage As Long, verticalCardsPage As Long, i As Long

Set originalWs = ActiveSheet
Set ws = Sheets.Add
wsRowCounter = 1
wsCollumCounter = 1
expansionSize = 175
cardRowSize = 13
cardCollumSize = 4
horizontalCardsPage = 3
verticalCardsPage = 3
originalWs.Activate


For i = 1 To expansionSize

    originalWs.Range("C14") = i
    originalWs.Range("B2:E14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws.Activate

    If wsCollumCounter >= (cardCollumSize * horizontalCardsPage) Then
        wsRowCounter = wsRowCounter + cardRowSize
        ws.Rows(((wsRowCounter - 1) * verticalCardsPage) + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        wsCollumCounter = 1
    End If

    ws.Cells(wsRowCounter, wsCollumCounter).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    wsCollumCounter = wsCollumCounter + cardCollumSize
    originalWs.Activate
Next i
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: line 30:  ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: What about if you do a `ws.Cells(wsRowCounter, wsCollumCounter).paste` instead; removing the `.activate`. It's less ambiguous.

Comment: If I ask to paste side by side in the same line, or down in the same collum, it works. But not as a "Matrix" style.

Comment: You can scrap that `ws.Activate` as well as it's superfluous. Then also change that `originalWs.Range("B2:E14").Select` and subsequent `.copy` to just be a `originalWs.Range("B2:E14").Copy` and get out of all this unnecessary `.select` and `.activate` code.

Comment: With 'ws.Cells(wsRowCounter, wsCollumCounter).paste', I get an error that is: "The object doesn't accept this property or method"

Comment: When I do those changes, I get a range error, on the `ws.Cells(wsRowCounter, wsCollumCounter).activate`

Comment: I just added an answer with a bit of a rewrite. Getting rid of `.select` and `.activate` since those really aren't necessary and lead to some ambiguity. Also performing the copy/paste in one line using the `Destination:=` parameter of the Range's `.Copy` method. This still may throw an error, but I think this will help narrow down the troubleshooting if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain this will fix the issue, but it does help get rid of some of the ambiguity and whatnot:

```
Dim originalWs As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim wsRowCounter As Long, wsCollumCounter As Long, expansionSize As Long, cardRowSize As Long, cardCollumSize As Long
Dim horizontalCardsPage As Long, verticalCardsPage As Long, i As Long

Set originalWs = ActiveSheet
Set ws = Sheets.Add
wsRowCounter = 1
wsCollumCounter = 1
expansionSize = 175
cardRowSize = 13
cardCollumSize = 4
horizontalCardsPage = 3
verticalCardsPage = 3

For i = 1 To expansionSize

    originalWs.Range("C14") = i

    If wsCollumCounter >= (cardCollumSize * horizontalCardsPage) Then
        wsRowCounter = wsRowCounter + cardRowSize
        ws.Rows(((wsRowCounter - 1) * verticalCardsPage) + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        wsCollumCounter = 1
    End If  

    'perform the copy/paste in one line:
    originalWs.Range("B2:E14").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(wsRowCounter, wsCollumCounter)    

    wsCollumCounter = wsCollumCounter + cardCollumSize    
Next i
```

Comment: Fantastic! I would have been stumped had it still errored. I'm still stumped as to why your original code was erroring. It was a bit round-a-bout, but it made sense.